# Created DropDown Menu with Live Data from Another Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a patients table, and a treatments table.  Pretty standard.  Inside of the treatments table I have a few string fields and it is not relational to anything.  Let's leave it at that for now (thought it will need to be I assume).  Then the patients table is relational to a user, but I don't think that is relevant.

What I am trying to do is get a dropdown list of current patients to show up in the form when you create a treatment.  So treatment/_form would have something that shows a dropdown list of current patients.  The way a patient is created is super simple a user must be logged in, then they create a patient using a CRUD method (and in that table is just basically a name:string, and phone:string).  So I just want those names to show up in a dropdown on the treatments form.

With that being said I realize the treatment area will need to be relational to the patient area.  SO I have that all set up, so let's move right into implementation and what I've done thus far.

So far what I've done is set this all up in a hardcoded way.  Now I need help getting it to work dynamically.  Here is the hard coded version:

On treatment form:

```
<%= f.label "Client or Patient Name:" %>
<%= f.collection_select :patient, Treatment::PATIENTS, :to_s, :titleize %>
```

In Treatment model:

```
PATIENTS = %w[John Jim Max Cathy]

  def role_symbols
    [patient.to_sym]
  end
```

And of course I added the patient:string column to treatment table to get that to work.  But that works beautifully.  Now I just want that PATIENTS array to have live data.  I noticed in models you can't do things like PATIENTS = %w[Patient.all], so  how exactly would I go about doing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `app/views/treatments/_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:patient_id, Patient.all, :id, :name) %>
```

Should give you a dropdown of all patients

See:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#option-tags-from-a-collection-of-arbitrary-objects
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_select